# Delphi access violation only on specific computer

Tags: delphi, runtime-error

I'm on a project, which I had created on Computer 1 and now I wanted to edit and run it on Computer 2. Both Computers have the same operating system and the same Delphi version. As I tried to compile the project on Computer 2 (without modifying anything) an access violation showed up, although there were no problems on Computer 1.

It is an FMX project and the access violation occurs in **`System.Win.OleControls`** in the **`procedure TDelegatedOleControl.CreateControl;`** in the line containing "**`OleCheck(FPersistStream.InitNew)`**".

The error occurs before the GUI of my app shows up, so how can I know, what part of my code is responsible for this?

Normally I try to find errors by adding stuff to a Memo to see, where something goes wrong, but as this error occurs before I can see anything I would like to know how to know, where this happens.

When I continue and ignore this exception playing around with the app seems like nothing is impacted as everything works as expected. Unfortunately there's another issue. I've got a TWebbrowser on a frame inside the app. On Computer 1 everything worked fine, but on computer 2 it shows a bunch of access violation errors when I try to load a site. However also this doesn't impact the usage of the app.

The webbrowser thows about something like 40 errors, from which the very most of them were in **`FMX.Platform.Win`** in the **`function TPlatformWin.HandleMessage: Boolean;`** in the line containing **`if FIsPostQuitMessage then`**

*This is not really important to me as I can also continue using computer 1, where no errors occur, but computer 2 is a bit faster, so it would be nice to get this errors fixed on computer 2.*

What could possibly cause this errors and why are they showing up on computer 2 exclusively?

**Update**

Originally the project was a VCL project which I managed to "convert" into an FMX project. I've done this many versions ago and it was not a problem as it worked and also I just reused the visual components, which would be painful to recreate manually as it was a lot of work. Could this possibly have caused the errors? I can't really belive this would be the reason as computer 1 had no problems at all

**Update2**

The Error on app startup occurs even before `FormCreate` is called, so I don't know kow to track this error as nothing from my code seems to be responsible.

**Update3**

I forgot to mention, that I started developing the project on computer 2, then I moved to computer 1 and it worked fine and as I tried to get back to computer 2 the situation explained above occured.

**Update4**
The error before the FormCreate procedure starts is [this](https://pasteboard.co/GWspy4V.png) and it points to [this](https://pasteboard.co/GWsqwsT.png)
I removed IE a long time ago and forgot about it. This should be the issue as on computer1 IE is still available and there are no errors showing up.

Comment: "_Both Computers have ... Delphi_" Debug it on the second computer. Make sure you enable debug DCUs first.

Comment: No code, no description of errors... how can anyone possibly know what the problem is here?

Comment: Posted the error screenshots below an answer, I'll update this to the main post in a few hours, when I have access to my PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is coming in urlmon.dll. problem is due to IE, not your application ,suggested solution is to remove and reinstall IE or repair it

Try methods given at this URL https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/10316551/Access-violation-fault-in-module-urlmon-dll.html

Comment: I think thats it. I removed my IE due to.. reasons.. long time ago. Possibly this affected my TWebbrowser as it is based on IE. I'll reinstall IE and let you know if this fixed it. I just forgot, that I removed IE^^ Thanks for this reminder.

Comment: do mark this as answer if it helped you.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like permission issue.try running your application with admin privileges. It is good choice to put debug points or logs to see exactly where this error is coming

Comment: How can I run this app as admin? Should I start Delphi as admin or do I have to change the way my app is called? Also my app doesn't do any admin stuff, so why would this solve the problem?

Comment: running delphi as admin didn't help.

Comment: Can you please share the detailed exception ??

Comment: Please share detailed exception

Comment: [This](https://pasteboard.co/GWspy4V.png) error is forwarded to [this](https://pasteboard.co/GWsqwsT.png) piece of code